# pip is showing that its upgraded but it's not?

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

I am trying to install pygame on my pc but the process was getting finished by exit code -1. So some people recommended to upgrade it ***(my old one was 7.1.0)*** After upgrading, I am still seeing `7.1.0`

***Command:***

`pip install --upgrade pip`

***What I got***

```
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 21.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' comm
and.
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/cf/0cc542fc93de2f3b9b5
3cb979c7d1118cffb93204afb46299a9f858e113f/pip-21.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-7.1.0
```

**So I mean that pip is still stuck at 7.1.0 instead it should have jumped to the latest??***

***Now when i try to see pip version by typing:***
`pip --version`

***it returns***
`pip 7.1.0 from c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip-7.1.0-py3.4.egg (python 3.4)`

Comment: Try running `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Or else you can install via wheel file also https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command:

$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip